# Docker Image with Nginx and running with docker compose and in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, aws-cli

I already have a docker file for customized image for nginx and this works fine.

```
FROM library/nginx:1.13.2
LABEL maintainer="san@test.com"

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log \
# Make PageSpeed cache writable
    && mkdir -p /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed && \
    chmod -R o+wr /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed
ADD server.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/
ADD server.key /etc/nginx/ssl/

ADD conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
ADD proxy.d/ /etc/nginx/proxy.d/
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I am trying to also have aws cli installed so I can copy some s3 files and dynamically change nginx configuration which i will do with CMD[] once awsCli is available within the container.

I tried and read many a links from google, but the documentation or reads are not helping especially how to have credentials passed.

I am creating the image in two ways. First is via jenkins pipeline (snippet below

```
stages {
        stage('Build Docker image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry("http://xyz-1.amazonaws.com", "ecr:eu-central-1:aws-credentials") {
                        def customImage = docker.build("web-proxy:${CY_RELEASE_VERSION}", ".")
                        customImage.push()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And other way is in local I manually build the image like following

```
docker build -t web-proxy-dev_san_1:1.11 .
```

What I am not sure is how I can have aws-cli in DockerFile and have the image take credentials automatically both locally and in jenkins. I think for jenkins it may work if I manage to have aws-cli installed as I am using aws-credentials specified in pipeline but I havent reached that stage yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS plugin to interact AWS in your pipeline, check the following example: [link](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027893492-How-To-Authenticate-to-AWS-with-the-Pipeline-AWS-Plugin)